# Перекидывать на http протокол, если заходишь по ссылке ftp://

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Как сделать редирект на http/https протокол, если я захожу на сайт через ftp протокол, через адресную строку браузера?..

```
ftp://site.ru...
> http://site.ru
```

Сервер апач, может черз htaccess, или доп. конфигами...

Такое вообще, возможно?

Comment: это из области черной магии будет. маловероятно что такое в принципе реализуемо.

Comment: как вы себе представляете реализацию перенаправлений в протоколе, который в принципе не поддерживает перенаправления? Браузеры это в целом частный случай фтп-клиентов, многие из которых вообще консольные.